# How to disassemble rear wheel hub with no lock nut?

Tags: maintenance, hub

Please see pictures. My rear wheel has a Deda Elementi hub which has a Thru axle. I have removed my 11-speed cassette and disc rotor. There is no lock nut on the non-drive side. There only appears to be groves for one 17mm wrench. It is the same on the drive side. There is a slot inside the axle where I can place a 10mm Hex. I'm looking to get at the sealed bearings in the hub so I can replace them. On a previous rear wheel hub, I used two 17mm wrenches on the non-drive side. Any ideas?

[image: close-up of the non-drive side of the hub]
[image: close-up of the drive side of the hub]

Comment: I can't tell from your pictures; can you identify the particular model of the hub/wheel?  The [Deda Elementi website](https://dedaelementi.com/downloads/manuals) has a set of reasonably good manuals available, but you'd need to know which model to look up.

Comment: Yes. Page 11 here but I can't figure out what is the best way to open it. https://dedaelementi.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/download/Manuals/EN/SL30-45DB-62DB-EN.pdf

Answer (score 4):

I found the documentation for anyone who comes across this post.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site - thank you for posting your findings, it will definitely help the next person with the same problem.